# How to retrieve data from Excel using userform

Tags: excel, vba

I have data contained in "Sheet1" with only 2 columns. Column "A" and Column "B".

Below are my questions

1. The below code which is working fine, but at the moment, I have to put every single word within the cell to bring up a result. Is there a way there, where I can type only a word or a few words contained within that cell that it will bring up a result.
2. Is there a way, if I have 2 different results pulled from the data, like duplicates, what is the code to see the next. Do I need a command button like eg: `Next`

---

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cl As Range
    Dim vFind
    Dim R As Long

    Set rng = Sheet1.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))

    vFind = Me.TextBox1.Text
    With rng
        Set cl = .Find(vFind, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not cl Is Nothing Then R = cl.Row
        Me.TextBox2.Value = Cells(R, 2).Value
    End With
```

Comment: For the first part:  `Set cl = .Find(vFind, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart)`

Comment: Hmm it doesn't seem to work. Do you know the code if I add a button to see the next result if there are duplicate

Comment: If that doesn't work it would be useful to show an example input and an example expected match.  For the "multiple hits" part, take a look here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55072042/setting-up-find-next-and-find-previous-buttons-in-vba/55072549#55072549

Comment: It didn't help. Can someone guide me through it please?

Comment: This is not a tutorial site - to write this type of thing well is not super-simple, but there are plenty of examples to be found via Google.